# Connecting BigQuery and Google Sheets - DATE parameter issue

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-bigquery

following [1](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/connecting-bigquery-and-google-sheets-to-help-with-hefty-data-analysis) I started creating a Spreadsheet which reads data from BigQuery, but I'm having an issue handling parameters related to date values.

In the first sheet, I created 2 cells with 2 parameters, the start and the end of a date interval, with proper values. Both cells are formatted as "Date" value.

In the second sheet I configured BigQuery connector, for this example, I'm using a public dataset with dates. `bigquery-public-data.utility_eu.date_greg`

From the BigQuery connector wizard I added:

```
"STARTDATE" as "PARAMETERS!B1"
"ENDDATE" as "PARAMETERS!B2"
```

After this configuration, this is the resulting query:

```
SELECT
  date,
  date_str,
  date_int

FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_eu.date_greg` 

WHERE date > DATE(@STARTDATE) AND date < DATE(@ENDDATE)

LIMIT 10
```

I'm getting an error directly from the editor with this message:

```
> Error BigQuery: No matching signature for function DATE for argument types: INT64. Supported signatures: DATE(TIMESTAMP, [STRING]); DATE(DATETIME); DATE(INT64, INT64, INT64) at [8:14]
```

As far as I can understand, the "date" cells are retrieved as a number, so the direct parse is not working. After a couple of tests, I understood the that given int value is the number I can obtain change cell format to "number".
If you convert cell value from DATE to NUMBER you get this value:

```
01/05/2019 -> 43.586
31/05/2019 -> 43.616
```

What is this number? It is not milliseconds, it increases by 1 every next day. In order to create the proper query that can parse this int, I need to understand what is this int (of course I can handle the cell as "text" and writing the timestamp value directly, but I would prefer to have the native date format so I can use the built-in calendar.

My consideration (with simple math) is that this number refers to a number of days since `30/12/1899`, but it is very odd (also, every date BEFORE this days is always 0), so I'm asking you directly how to handle this value. Basing on my understanding of when the number counter starts (30/12/1899), I created this query which add the number retrieved from the cell:

```
SELECT *

FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_eu.date_greg`

WHERE 
  date >= DATE_ADD(DATE("1899-12-30"), INTERVAL @DATAINIZIO DAY)
  AND date <= DATE_ADD(DATE("1899-12-30"), INTERVAL @DATAFINE DAY)
```

It is working... but I think I'm doing a workaround that is not the proper way of doing this.

Also, is there any full documentation related to this BigQuery connection provided by Spreadsheet? Besides presentation in [1](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/connecting-bigquery-and-google-sheets-to-help-with-hefty-data-analysis) I'm unable to find any specific documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Spreadsheets (Google, Excel, ...) store the dates as days passed since a starting date with a fractional day representing time.

From [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm): "Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of days since 1900-Jan-0, plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day:   ddddd.tttttt . This is called a serial date, or serial date-time."

Now, you have to ways to filter by date on your Query:

1. In the query, you can use DATE_ADD to add your number of days (cell value) to the base date. (Carefull, DATE_ADD takes INT, and the date value is float so needs prior casting).
2. (preferred) on your spreadsheet you use TEXT(cell, "yyyy-mm-dd") so you can then use DATE() in the BigQuery query.

I use the second method as, though you need that extra cell (unless you directly store the date as YYYY-MM-DD; keeps the query cleaner than having a cast and date_add in there. Also would save you from the "1904 problem" explained in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

> What is this number? It is not milliseconds, it increases by 1 every next day.

This is so called serial number which represent number of days since "very beginning"
Google's Spreadsheet date calendar starts from 1900-01-01 - which is treated as a "very beginning"

> In order to create the proper query that can parse this int, I need to understand what is this int

Armed with above info you can adjust you dates calculation to be in sync with what BigQuery expects

Comment: Also note - I think this feature (connected sheet) is still in early Beta

Comment: I don't know if beta or not, I'm unable to find any documentations besides the blog page where the functionality is introduced. At the end the BQ query I already made with the date_add seems to be the quickiest way to solve this issue

Comment: `Armed with above info you can adjust you dates calculation to be in sync with what BigQuery expects`
This is what I done and you can read in my query, but I'm using 30-12 as point of start, no 01-01 as you mentioned. I was wondering if it is the proper way to handle this kind of need.

Comment: I got it! somehow I totally missed the final part in your question and focused on question in the middle of your post that I thought is the main question. Anyway - yes - I do not know why but technically using "1899-12-30"in the query like you did is correct

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that your fields are already in Date format, maybe you are doing an extra parsing in your query.

Try to do it without the DATE functions.

Also, I found this other doc, not merely related to connection, but might be helpful: [Getting info from Spreadsheets with BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-crunch-your-business-data-from-sheets-in-bigquery).

Comment: Your link is related for the opposite kind of action, accessing Sheet data from BigQuery, as federated data source. I'm using the new connector built in Sheet to retrieve data from BigQuery. There is no parsing in the Query, I only use the parameter